# Woocommerce succinct code to auto add corresponding code blocks every time admin adds product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

So I've got some repetitive code below that, when an admin adds a new product category, I have to go in make and make sure I add yet another block of code with the newly added category.

```
if(is_product_category( 'animal' )) {
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'product_cat' => 'animal',
                'posts_per_page' => 999,
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',);
            } elseif(is_product_category( 'character' )) {
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'product_cat' => 'character',
                'posts_per_page' => 999,
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',);
            } elseif(is_product_category( 'kids' )) {
                $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'product_cat' => 'kids',
                'posts_per_page' => 999,
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',);
            } 
...
```

Since the only thing changing is the conditional statement and the product category array, I'm thinking there's a way to write one block of code that'll just take each newly created category and auto do it so I don't have to go back in.

Comment: Like reading the categories from a database?

Comment: @olaEkdahl I'm not sure what you mean. I'm just looking to write some code that auto adds the above blocks for me, changing out the correct category every time the admin adds a new product category.